# $A=\{-1,1\}$ and how to prove that $\sup A = 1$ using $\varepsilon$ criterion

Tags: real-analysis

Given $A$ - a non-empty set. Then $\sup A = x \iff \forall a \in A: a \leq x$ and also $\forall \varepsilon > 0: \exists a_{\varepsilon} \in A: a_{\varepsilon} > x - \varepsilon$ 
But if my set $A = \{ -1,1 \}$, it's kind of obvious that $\sup A = 1$. But how to show it using this $\varepsilon$-criterion? When the set contains a finite amount of elements

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take $x=1$ and $a_{\epsilon} = 1$ for all $\epsilon$.

Visualize.

Comment: Dang it, I forgot that 1 is in A. Now understood. Thanks and sorry for a stupid question

Answer (score -1):

In general, if $A$ has a maximum, then $\sup(A) = \max(A)$.

Comment: I know that, but I wanted to see, how this criterion works for the finite amount